# Call online php function

Tags: php, api, function, include

I have a question whether something is possible.

I have followed the setup:

A server with it on a server with php Horticultural file where php functions on it. Now I want to taget load on my local webserver and then call the function

SERVER:
API.php

```
<?php

function random_password() {

    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";

    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array

    $alpha_length = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache

    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {

        $n = rand(0, $alpha_length);

        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];

    }

    return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string

}

?>
```

local:
test_locaal.php

```
<?php

include "http://***api.new*******.nl/API.php";

print_r(random_password());
?>
```

I get the following error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function random_password() in E:\Webserver\root\API\test_online.php on line 5

Comment: When you include `API.php` as an http URL, the server executes it, and then returns its output. The output of `API.php` in this case is empty. So basically, you can't include a remote php file over HTTP unless you put it in plain text (e.g. change the file extension to `API.txt` or something similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is including the php file over http. This leads to PHP executing the php code and returning the result. But your api php file does not return any output.

What you might want to do is call your api via url as a service. Your API should run as a server, accepting requests and answering with a response.

There are quite a few tutorials on the web on how to accomplish this and there are quite a few libraries and frameworks as well.

- [Creating a RESTful API with PHP](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/)
- [Introduction to writing a REST server in PHP](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2009/01/13/introduction-to-writing-a-rest-server-in-php/)
- [REST API – A Simple PHP Tutorial](http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/02/rest-api-a-simple-php-tutorial/)
- [RESTful Webservices mit PHP](http://www.phpmonkeys.de/2012/01/12/restful-webservices-mit-php/)

To keep it simple thou, here's another thing you could do. Structure your api and simply call the file that delivers the output you need. i.e.:

**api/random_password.php**

```
<?php

$alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
$pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
$alpha_length = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
  $n = rand(0, $alpha_length);
  $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
}

echo json_encode(implode($pass)); //turn the array into a string and output it
```

**local: test_locaal.php**

```
<?php
$randomPassword = file_get_contents("http://***api.new*******.nl/api/random_password.php");

print_r($randomPassword);
```